# How to create the apple styled container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

If you goto Photos > Edit Photo > Markup > Color Palette you will see this kind of container. I only want the container style.

In the container you can see the contents that are behind the container partially. I tried to do that with opacity but it looks like it didn't work. It looks like the background is blurred a bit.

[image]

I tried to copy this container style like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Flutter")),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.network("https://i.imgur.com/CyEPpo2.jpg"),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 400,
                width: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  color: const Color(0xff222222).withOpacity(0.98),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Colors",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html

Comment: The container has a blurred background adds an opacity (around 90%) to it.

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks @someuser.